# getting `rsync -aF` to respect .rsync-filter

Tags: rsync

I am using rsnapshot to maintain a partial copy of the home directory on my Mac to an archive server. The relevant command in rsnapshot is

```
/usr/bin/rsync -azvF --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh garethhowell@172.29.12.159:/Users/garethhowell /import/archive/rsnapshot1/alpha.0/mbpro.agdon.net
```

To ensure there is only a partial copy, I use the following `.rsync-filter` file:

```
- /tmp*
- /temp
- /lost+found

# Office temporary files
- ~$*

# Common Mac junk
- .TemporaryItems
- .DS_Store/
- .Trash/
- ._*

# Specific stuff
- /Downloads/
- /VMWare/
- /VirtualBox\ VMs/
- /opt/

+ /Library/
+ /Library/Containers/
+ /Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/
- /Library/Containers/*/
- /Library/Containers/*
- /Library/*/
- /Library/*
```

I am having a problem trying the sync the iCloud folder. Basically, despite the filters, it is syncing the entire `Library` folder.

There's obviously something wrong near the end of the `.rsync-filter` file, but I can't see it.

Comment: Using `--relative` can change how some paths are compared. Try removing this option and suffixing `/Users/garethhowell` to the destination (`/import...`).  I assume the `.rsync-filter` file is in `/Users/garethhowell`?

Comment: Worth a try. Thanks

Comment: That looks like it may have done it. Thanks